# XAML Treeview, how to displayed nodes horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, treeview

I'm kinda new at XAML and I'm trying to figure how to display the TreeView nodes horizontally instead of vertically, i.e

```
Header 1
  Item 1 Item 2 item 3
Header 2
  Item 4
```

Instead of

```
Header 1
  Item 1
  Item 2
  Item 3
Header 2
  Item 4
```

It's not really as simple as it seems, I was able to get the headers to go horizontally though...

XAML Code below

```
<Grid >      
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ApplicationListViewModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ApplicationViewModel}" >                    
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ListView>                        
                    <Button>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    </Button>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

If it helps to know what I'm trying to accomplish with my code, then basically I'm trying to organise applications in a series of categories. A container(like a list box) is generated for each application category.

The data structure I have is

```
Application Collection
   Application List (1-> Many)
      Application (1-> Many)
```

Comment: I posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42860839/3063273) to a very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/364083/3063273). It might be helpful to people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a codeproject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx?msg=1877610) that explains exactly how to do this... Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yup that answers the question perfectly, thank you. 
I passed over that article initially cause I wouldn't have thought about using styles to do that.